# increasing width of figure in matplotlib according to number of x values

Tags: python, width, matplotlib, figure

I was trying to draw a `barchart` using `matplotlib`.The number of items to be plotted can vary . I cannot set the `figure.set_size_inches(w,h)` or `set_figwidth(w)` with  constants(like 6.,8. or 8.,12. etc),since I cannot tell in advance what the value of w or h should be.I want the `width of figure to increase as the number of items to be plotted increases`.Can someone tell me how I can do this?

```
import pylab

def create_barchart(map):
    xvaluenames = map.keys()
    xvaluenames.sort()
    yvalues = map.values()
    max_yvalue = get_max_yvalue(yvalues)
    xdata = range(len(xvaluenames))
    ydata = [map[x] for x in xvaluenames]
    splitxdata = [x.split('-',1) for x in xvaluenames]
    xlabels = [x[0] for x in splitxdata]
    figure = pylab.figure()
    ax = figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    figsize = figure.get_size_inches()
    print 'figure size1=',figsize,'width=',figsize[0],'height=',figsize[1]
    barwidth = .25
    ystep =  max_yvalue/5
    pylab.grid(True)
    if xdata and ydata:
        ax.bar(xdata, ydata, width=barwidth,align='center',color='orange')
        ax.set_xlabel('xvalues',color='green')
        ax.set_ylabel('yvalues',color='green')
        ax.set_xticks(xdata)
        ax.set_xlim([min(xdata) - 0.5, max(xdata) + 0.5])
        ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
        ax.set_yticks(range(0,max_yvalue+ystep,ystep))
        ax.set_ylim(0,max(ydata)+ystep)
    figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=30)
    figure.savefig('mybarplot',format="png")
    print 'figure size2=',figure.get_size_inches()
    pylab.show()

def get_max_yvalue(yvals):
    return max(yvals) if yvals else 0
```

if I try with a small set of items,I get

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    datamap = dict(mark=39,jim=40, simon=20,dan=33)    
    print datamap
    create_barchart(datamap)
```

[image: plot of small set]

but if I use a larger set

```
datamap = dict(mark=39,jim=40, simon=20,dan=33) 
additional_values= dict(jon=34,ray=23,bert=45,kevin=35,ned=31,bran=11,tywin=56,tyrion=30,jaime=36,griffin=25,viserys=25)
datamap.update(additional_values)  
create_barchart(datamap)
```

[image: plot of a larger set]

This looks awful,
I am wondering if there is a way to increase the width of figure,according to the number of items to be plotted,keeping the width of bars in both cases same

Comment: `len(map)` should give you the number of bars and you know this going into the function.  Why can't you set the width of the chart based on this value?  Seems something is missing in your example.  Is it supposed to be interactive?

Comment: no,it is not supposed to be interactive..should have figured out the scaling of width based on number of items..that was a case of my braincells going to sleep:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the width when you initialize the figure:

```
# default scale is 1 in your original case, scales with other cases:
widthscale = len(yvalues)/4 
figsize = (8*widthscale,6) # fig size in inches (width,height)
figure = pylab.figure(figsize = figsize) # set the figsize
```

Replace the `figure = pylab.figure()` line with the above three lines and you get what your asking for.